# Remove every comma in string except last one with python

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have those strings

```py
s1 = "1,395,54"
s2 = "1,5,6,75"
```

I would like all commas except the last to obtain the following strings:

```py
s1 = "1395,54"
s2 = "156,75"
```

What is the most efficient way to solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution with `str.replace`. `replace` function accepts a third argument which specifies *Maximum number of occurrences to replace*. So you can pass a number which is one less than the number of occurrences of `,` in your string(`your_string.count(",") - 1`).

```
>>> s1 = "1,395,54"
>>> s1.replace(",", "", s1.count(",") - 1)
'1395,54'
>>> s2 = "1,5,6,75"
>>> s2.replace(",", "", s2.count(",") - 1)
'156,75'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split and rejoin with `f-strings` -

```py
*rest, last = s1.split(',')
f'{"".join(rest)},{last}'
```

You can combine those into a one liner -

`''.join(s1.split(',')[:-1]) + "," + s1.split(',')[-1]`

Comment: Can avoid double split computation in one liner with: `''.join((p:=s1.split(','))[:-1]) + "," + p[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a pattern asserting that there is a comma present to the right with only digits in between:

```
import re

s1 = "1,395,54"
s2 = "1,5,6,75"

pattern = r",(?=\d*,)"

print(re.sub(pattern, "", s1))  # 1395,54
print(re.sub(pattern, "", s2))  # 156,75
```

The broader variant accepting any char except a comma inbetween:

```
,(?=[^,]*,)
```